# OAuth access Token fails while accessing twitter from iOS 5

Tags: xcode, twitter, oauth, ios5

I am using MGTwitterEngine" to Integrate twitter in my app.It works fine up to iOS 4.2 . When I try to access twitter from any of the iOS 5 device , I am experiencing an authentication token issue.

`This page is no longer valid. It looks like someone already used the token information you provided. Please return to the site that sent you to this page and try again ... it was probably an honest mistake`

After a lot of googling I found some suggestions .But they didn't solve my issue.
Tried https instead http .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try replacing

Request token URL

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Authorize URL

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize

Access token URL

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token

I this this should work.

Comment: Ya it worked fine .But the server seems to be down most of the times

Comment: It still shows error message for me about "request token for this page is invalid". Login screen can't be opened for Twitter.

Comment: Set the value for clearCookies to YES and you will be fine with it then!

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem detecting iOS version in order to use MGTwitterEngine for iOS 4.3 and earlier version and TWRequest and Twitter API for iOS5.

```
NSString *requiredVersion = @"5.";

NSRange aRange = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] rangeOfString:requiredVersion];


if (aRange.location == NSNotFound )
{
      //MGTwitterEngine here
} else {
      //Twitter API here
}
```

This works for me, I hope it will do it for you.

Comment: Where to put this conditional logic, I need to implement iOS 5 Twitter API and < 5.0 APIs also..!

Comment: Put it on your "Send Tweet" button event in order to use the correct API for each iOS version.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above solutions, but these were not able to fix this issue. Finally I did this:

*requestRequestToken* set new request token

```
 [engine requestRequestToken];// added this to remove the old request token because old request token will not work with new authentication request 
 UIViewController *controller = [[SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:engine delegate:self] retain];  
 [delegate presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
```

Note: It increases the time of loading a web view.

I think it will help.